# Compressing two integers disregarding order

Tags: information-theory, data-compression

Comparing an ordered pair (x,y) to an unordered pair {x, y} (set), then information theoretically, the difference is only one bit, as whether x comes first or y requires exactly a single bit to represent.

So, if we're given a set {x,y} where x,y are two different 32-bit integers, can we pack them into 63 bits (rather 64)?  It should be possible to recover the original 32 bit integers from the 63 bit result, but without being able to recover their order.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, one can.  If $x<y$, map the set $\{x,y\}$ to the number

$$f(x,y) = y(y-1)/2 + x.$$

It is easy to show that $f$ is bijective, and so this can be uniquely decoded.   Also, when $0 \le x < y < 2^{32}$, we have $0 \le f(x,y) < 2^{63} - 2^{31}$, so this maps the set $\{x,y\}$ to a 63-bit number $f(x,y)$.  To decode, you can use binary search on $y$, or take a square root: $y$ should be approximately $\lfloor \sqrt{2 f(x,y)} \rfloor$.

Comment: just like 1+2+3+...+y+x nice!

Comment: any generalization to n unordered ints? :)
on second thought, many quadforms with large enough partial derivatives will do the job

Comment: @D.W.: Did you intend to add the restriction that the numbers be different when you edited the question? The answer is very different if the numbers are allowed to be the same.

Comment: Another answer that may be attractive for its low computation cost: if `x` and `y` are different, then either `x-y-1` or `y-x-1` (both mod $2^{32}$, of course) fits in 31 bits. If `x-y-1` is small, then concatenate `y` and the last 31 bits of `x-y-1`; otherwise concatenate `x` and the last 31 bits of `y-x-1`. Recover the two numbers by taking the first 32 bits as one number and adding the first 32 bits, the last 31 bits, and the constant 1 (mod $2^{32}$) as the other.

Comment: your method also generalize nicely to adding more numbers, as the first number is "just there" so can chain

Comment: @TroyMcClure that only saves one bit for every extra item. The binomial reduction offers much more savings to be had.

Comment: @SteveCox With more numbers, there are more opportunities to find orderings with low-bit-count-differences towards the tail, to the point that you should be able to drop off more bits the farther you go into the tail. I think one can probably suitably generalize the approach -- but perhaps with some costly search among permutations during encoding. I haven't thought about it hard enough to see if there's something clever you can do to avoid the search, but that may be possible, too.

Comment: @TroyMcClure If you want to read scholarly articles about related techniques, try including "succinct data structure" in your searches -- there's a whole cottage industry around discovering cute tricks for this stuff.

Comment: With four items you should be able to gain floor(log_2 4!)=4 bits. Pairwise merges only gain you three. Unpacking them can still recover those 1.6 extra bits of information about how these numbers were paired originally.

Comment: @D.W.: Could you please also add *how* you came up with this representation? Otherwise it seems like you pulled it out of thin air.

Comment: @DanielWagner Why don't you post your solution as a separate answer?

Comment: @DanielWagner i don't see a generalization of the approach that yields the correct reduction in the limit (an unordered set of $2^{32}-1$ entries must be encoded in just 32 bits), but i too haven't thought about it long enough.

Comment: @TroyMcClure See my answer for a generalisation.

Comment: @SteveCox Note that, from the formula in my answer, sets of $ k = 2^{32}-1$ entries would be encoded in the range $[0:k]$.

Comment: @SteveCox encoding an unordered set of $2^32-1$ entries in 32 bits is actually rather easy

Comment: @JanDvorak no doubt, which is why its a perfect example to test the limits of a method

Answer (score 10):

As an addition to D.W.'s answer, note that this is a particular case of the [Combinatorial Number System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system), which compactly maps a strictly decreasing sequence of $k$ non-negative integers $c_k > \cdots > c_1$ to
$$ N = \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{c_i}{i}.$$

This number has a simple interpretation. If we order these sequences lexicographically, then $N$ counts the number of smaller sequences.

To decode, just assign $c_k$ the largest value such that $\binom{c_k}{k} \leq N$ and decode $N - \binom{c_k}{k}$ as a $(k-1)$-sequence.

Answer (score 4):

The total number of unordered pairs of numbers in a set of $N$ is $N(N+1)/2$. The total number of unordered pairs of *distinct* numbers is $N(N-1)/2$. It takes $2 \log_2(N) = \log_2(N^2)$ bits to represent an ordered pair of numbers, and if you have one less bit, you can represent elements of a space of up to $N^2/2$. The number of unordered not-necessarily-distinct pairs is slightly more than half the number of ordered pairs so you can't save a bit in the representation; the number of unordered distinct pairs is slightly less than half, so you can save a bit.

For a practical scheme that's easy to compute, with $N$ being a power of 2, you can work on the bitwise representation. Take $a = x \oplus y$ where $\oplus$ is the XOR (bitwise exclusive or) operator. The pair $\{x,y\}$ can be recovered from either $(a, x)$ or $(a, y)$. Now we'll look for a trick to save one bit in the second part, and give a symmetric role to $x$ and $y$ so that the order cannot be recovered. Given the cardinality computation above, we know this scheme will not work in the case where $x=y$.

If $x \ne y$ then there is some bit position where they differ. I'll write $x_i$ for the $i$th bit of $x$ (i.e. $x = \sum_i x_i 2^i$), and likewise for $y$. Let $k$ take the smallest bit position where $x$ and $y$ differ: $k$ is the smallest $i$ such that $x_i \ne y_i$. $k$ is the smallest $i$ such that $a_i = 1$: we can recover $k$ from $a$. Let $b$ be either $x$ or $y$ with the $k$th bit erased (i.e. $b = \sum_{i<k} x_i 2^i + \sum_{i>k} x_i 2^{i-1}$ or $b = \sum_{i<k} y_i 2^i + \sum_{i>k} y_i 2^{i-1}$) — to make the construction symmetric, pick $x$ if $x_k=0$ and $y_k=1$, and pick $y$ if $x_k=1$ and $y_k=0$. Use $(a,b)$ as the compact representation of the pair. The original pair can be recovered by computing the lowest-order bit that is set in $a$, inserting a 0 bit at this position in $b$ (yielding one of $x$ or $y$), and taking the xor of that number with $a$ (yielding the other element of the pair).

In this representation, $a$ can be any nonzero number, and $b$ can be any number with half the range. This is a sanity check: we get exactly the expected number of representations of unordered pairs.

In pseudocode, with `^`, `&`, `|`, `<<`, `>>`, `~` being C-like bitwise operators (xor, and, or, left-shift, right-shift, complement):

```
encode(x, y) =
  let a = x ^ y
  let k = lowest_set_bit_position(a)
  let low_mask = (1 << k) - 1
  let z = if x & (1 << k) = 0 then x else y
  return (a, (z & low_mask) | (z & ~low_mask) >> 1)
decode(a, b) =
  let k = lowest_set_bit_position(a)
  let low_mask = (1 << k) - 1
  let x = (b & low_mask) | ((b & ~low_mask) << 1)
  return (x, a ^ x)
```

Answer (score 0):

A nonconstructive proof: there are $(2^{32}\times 2^{32} - 2^{32})/2 = 2^{31}(2^{32}-1)<2^{63}$ unordered pairs of different 32-bit integers.